# When is the best way to add CALayers/CAGradientLayers to UITableViewCells or UICollectionViewCells for iOS 8.3?

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, cagradientlayer

I created a class method to create a gradient layer that can be added to any view I want.

```
+ (CAGradientLayer *)createPartialGradientWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    UIColor *color1 = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.00f];
    UIColor *color2 = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.10f];
    UIColor *color3 = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.25f];
    UIColor *color4 = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.50f];
    UIColor *color5 = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.75f];

    NSArray *colors = @[(id)color1.CGColor,
                        (id)color2.CGColor,
                        (id)color3.CGColor,
                        (id)color4.CGColor,
                        (id)color5.CGColor];

    NSNumber *stop1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.00f];
    NSNumber *stop2 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.25f];
    NSNumber *stop3 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.50f];
    NSNumber *stop4 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.75f];
    NSNumber *stop5 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.00f];

    NSArray *locations = @[stop1, stop2, stop3, stop4, stop5];

    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.colors = colors;
    gradientLayer.locations = locations;
    gradientLayer.frame = frame;

    return gradientLayer;
}
```

I want to use it as a background layer for my cells in a tableview or collection view.

If I just add it during initialisation, the frames will be wrong if the view controllers use auto layout.

I also tried to use this code inside the cell subclass:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    aGradientLayer.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
}
```

It works sometimes but, for iOS 8.3, when the view appears, the frame is still not fit.

Edit: Updated code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

1. initialize in the "init" method (or any other extension of init) and in the "layoutSubviews" method, resize it, but MAKE SURE TO CALL [super layoutSubviews]!
2. Use [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds and some math to calculate the width / height of the cell.

I'd go with number 1. If you don't call [super layoutSubviews], the contentView may not get resized correctly.

Comment: Yes (edited the code block), updating the frame during layoutSubviews is, by far, the best working solution but I have a new problem, for UITableViews, the first instance after viewWillAppear shrinks the width.

Comment: Check to see that nothing is happening in your viewWillAppear of your tableview that resizes it?

Comment: No UI update code anywhere inside the .m file except for the autolayout in the nib file.